# How to partially download a telegram file in with pyrogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyrogram

Actually I need to download first few chunks of a file(video/audio/etc) for the sake of mediainfo.

pyrogram:
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/stop_transmission
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/bound-methods/Message.download

progress fn (stops transmission when 1% of file has been downloaded)

```
    def prog(curr, total, client):
      print(curr * 100 / total, '%', flush=True)
      if curr * 100 / total >= 1:
        client.stop_transmission()
```

implementation

```
    tmp = msg.download(progress=prog, in_memory=True, progress_args=(client,))
    print(type(tmp), flush=True)
    with open(f'{msg.id}', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tmp.getvalue())
```

What output I am getting is:

```
1.8244671728371091 %
<class 'NoneType'>
```

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K85UH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All I need is to download only about 1% of a file with pyrogram telegram API. I cant show my whole complicated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`stream_media()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/stream_media%0A) function to Download chunks of a file

Here it will Download first 2 chunks of a Document

```
media=message.document
with open(media.file_name, "wb") as file:
    async for chunk in client.stream_media(message=media, limit=2):
        file.write(chunk)
```

Here is a Complete Example https://github.com/DeekshithSH/pyro-test/blob/main/DownloadMediaChunks.py

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32066799)

Comment: Ya, It happend to me many times with link reference to telethon docs. Now i have Edited the Answer